# retrieving symbols instead of arabic characters when accessing teradata database using spring boot jdbcTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, teradata, jdbctemplate

I am trying to retrieve data from teradata database using spring JDBCTemplate , all data are returned correctly except for the columns containing arabic text , they are returning as symbols instead of arabic text

[Corrupted Arabic Letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJn9k.png)

[connections properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BjGr.png)

Comment: You told Spring to expect UTF-8 but your database connection is defaulting to (extended) ASCII. Append the session character set option to the URL `jdbc:teradata://PREPRD/database=DP_OIC_VEW,charset=UTF8`

Comment: BTW - please post information as text unless an image is specifically needed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks Fred , it works fine , really appreciate your support